# Draw a 3D sphere with radius with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

Draw a sphere with radius with TikZ. According to the figure

[image]

Comment: may this can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345420/how-to-draw-a-bloch-sphere/345423#345423

Comment: some of the other answers suggested show very nice spheres, but none provides coding for the radius, which is an explicit request here.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is always hard to get answers to questions on the form "draw this for me" without showing any effort your self. Next time try to start a solution and add a MWE to your question, then you have much higher chance of getting someone to dig into your problem.

Here I guess the problem is the equator, where you can use `\arc` with different x- and y-radius.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.4] (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \draw (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
  \draw[dashed] (2,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
  \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$r$} (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]